# wordpress dropdown select and insert database

Tags: database, wordpress

How do I select data from database in dropdown and how do I insert the data in database for wordpress.

I used a foreach it shows the name but not the dropdown:

```
<div class="resform">
    <form method="POST" class="resform2"  action="">
        <div class="main_form_input">

            <?php
            global $wpdb;
            include "D:/wampserver/www/phpsite/wp-config.php";
            include "D:/wampserver/www/phpsite/wp-load.php"; 

            $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `dranklijst`");

            echo "<select>";

            foreach ( $result as $row ) 
            { 
                echo '<option value="">' . $row->drank_naam . '</option>';
                echo "</select>";
            }
            ?>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The line `echo "<select";` is incorrect. It should be `echo "<select>";`. Now, what else do you want to accomplish?

Comment: thx i didn't see that :) i want also now how to insert

Comment: Need help with the insertion to DB, you mentioned. If so, please elaborate on that.

Comment: If you have the global $wpdb variable you don't need to include wp-load and wp-config

Answer (score 0):

Get the values which you need to insert and follow below reference to insert 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row

Then no need below lines just global $wpdb is enough, if your action with in wordpress,

Remove below, 
include "D:/wampserver/www/phpsite/wp-config.php";
include "D:/wampserver/www/phpsite/wp-load.php";